# MySQL Dump using --all-databases

Tags: mysql, dump

I'm trying to create a full backup of multiple databases in MySQL using the `--all-databases` command but the output sql file is always only 1kb.

When I specify each database individually using just the `--databases` command the databases are backed up but it does not restore all tables when I upload the dump file to another MySQL installation.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: The reduced size of the dump seems an error that you are ignoring. ¿Could you provide the content of the output sql?

Comment: The contents of the output .sql file are

Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]
OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]
For more options, use mysqldump --help

Comment: The code I used for the dump was

MySQLDump -u (username) -p(password) --all-databases --masterdata > C:\OutputSQL\dump.sql